# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table contacts has no column named uid

Tags: android, sqlite

this is my code :

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
{
    String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS" 
            + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," // and auto increment will be handled with                            primary key
            + KEY_UID + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_NAME + " TEXT," 
            + KEY_PH_NO + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_Comapny + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_email + " TEXT," 
            + KEY_country + " TEXT," 
            + KEY_street + " TEXT," 
            + KEY_city + " TEXT,"+ KEY_state + " TEXT," 
            + KEY_zip + " TEXT);";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
}
```

I am getting below exception  :

```
: E/SQLiteDatabase(2645): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table contacts has no column named uid (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO contacts(uid,zip,phone_number,email,company_name,street,name,state,city,country) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

Please help.
Thanks

Comment: Here KEY_UID==uid???? Right? and please show insert method.

Comment: Could you show your field definitions and your insert statement, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a syntax error in your `CREATE TABLE` so obviously it has not been run. You need a space between `EXISTS` and the table name.

Since `onCreate()` with your current SQL has not been run, you have an older version of your database file around. Uninstall your app to remove it and make `onCreate()` run again. See [When is SQLiteOpenHelper onCreate() / onUpgrade() run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881992/when-is-sqliteopenhelper-oncreate-onupgrade-run) for more.

Comment: actually installing the newer version app works !! Thanks a lot for quick reply

Answer (score 1):

Replace this query:

```
String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS" 
                + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," // and auto increment will be handled with                            primary key
                + KEY_UID + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_NAME + " TEXT," 
                + KEY_PH_NO + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_Comapny + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_email + " TEXT," 
                + KEY_country + " TEXT," 
                + KEY_street + " TEXT," 
                + KEY_city + " TEXT,"+ KEY_state + " TEXT," 
                + KEY_zip + " TEXT);";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
```

with this:

```
String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " 
                + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," // and auto increment will be handled with                            primary key
                + KEY_UID + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_NAME + " TEXT," 
                + KEY_PH_NO + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_Comapny + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_email + " TEXT," 
                + KEY_country + " TEXT," 
                + KEY_street + " TEXT," 
                + KEY_city + " TEXT,"+ KEY_state + " TEXT," 
                + KEY_zip + " TEXT);";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
```

**Note:** There is a syntax error in your CREATE TABLE query, You need a space between EXISTS and the TABLE_CONTACTS.

Answer (score 0):

Here is Solution :
i facing same issue and now i fix it

we you want to make database app then
you have two java classes
first for  Parameters
`Params.java` , and other is `Contact.java` where  we make constructors, getter&setter etc.

`Param.java` Class Code Below: **(see Error in Line:5 and 6)** and fix that reference

```
package com.andro.background.crud_db.param;

public class Params {
    public static final int DB_VERSION=1;
    public static final String DB_NAME="contacts_db"; //(-_-)check this, My mistake was "contact_db" , i write wrong name so it shows error
    public static final String TABLE_NAME="contacts_table"; // Right is "contact_table", this kinda error in your code

    //key of our table in db
    public static final String KEY_ID="id";
    public static final String KEY_NAME="name";
    public static final String KEY_PHONE="phone_number";
}
```

(check this error in upper code)
if you do same mistake then your error will be like this below code

```
2020-02-03 02:57:24.432 10705-10705/com.andro.background.cruddb E/SQLiteLog: (1) table contacts_table has no column named phone_number
2020-02-03 02:57:24.434 10705-10705/com.andro.background.cruddb E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting name=sunnykanumber phone_number=9090909090
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table contacts_table has no column named phone_number (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO contacts_table(name,phone_number) VALUES (?,?)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:890)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:501)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1546)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1417)
        at com.andro.background.cruddb.data.MyDbHandler.addContact(MyDbHandler.java:62)
        at com.andro.background.cruddb.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```